# How to troubleshoot database writing process via admin-ajax.php in WordPress?

Tags: linux, mysql, php, wordpress, webmin

I have siteA.com (live) and siteB.com (staging) which **both are identical WordPress sites** sitting in a single EC2 server using Webmin with CentOS, MySQL, PHP.

The issue is that when I perform the same booking on each site which calls the admin-ajax.php, it took **siteA 13 seconds** to complete the booking but **only 2 seconds for siteB**.

How could I troubleshoot to find out what's wrong with siteA?

Comment: This question is more suitable in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you want, "troubleshoot database writing" or "find out what's wrong with siteA"?  In case it's the former, I'd check MySQL's slow query log.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes, of course. Slow query log. thx!